# Tile-based game with DirectX - issues with transparency and StretchRect

Tags: 2d, directx, rendering, tiles, transparency

In my current project I have a class which loads a map file and then it should load all associated tilesets (no transparent tiles - I used to work with magenta as a colorkey) and precreate a surface for each static layer of the map so I only have to display one bigger image per frame rather then iterating over all of my tiles. For each tileset I have a loop which loads them successfully like this

```
 IDirect3DSurface9 *pTilesetSurface = nullptr;
 // Create surface
 HRESULT hResult = Engine::GetInstance()->GraphicsDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(
      pTileset->GetImage()->GetWidth(),
      pTileset->GetImage()->GetHeight(),
      D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,
      D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
      &pTilesetSurface,
      nullptr);
 if(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
      return FALSE;

 // Load tileset
 std::wstring strTilesetSource(
      pTileset->GetImage()->GetSource().begin(),
      pTileset->GetImage()->GetSource().end());
 strTilesetSource = strPathToMap + strTilesetSource;
 hResult = ::D3DXLoadSurfaceFromFile(
      pTilesetSurface,
      nullptr,
      nullptr,
      strTilesetSource.c_str(),
      nullptr,
      D3DX_FILTER_LINEAR,
      D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 0, 255),
      nullptr);
 if(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
      return FALSE;

 this->m_vTilesets.push_back(pTilesetSurface);
```

After this loop I am iterating over every layer of the map and trying to build a surface for each layer with the associated tiles like this.

```
IDirect3DSurface9 *pLayerSurface = nullptr;
HRESULT hResult = Engine::GetInstance()->GraphicsDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(
    pLayer->GetWidth() * 16,
    pLayer->GetHeight() * 16,
    D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8,
    D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
    &pLayerSurface,
    nullptr);
if(!SUCCEEDED(hResult))
    return FALSE;
Engine::GetInstance()->GraphicsDevice->ColorFill(
    pLayerSurface,
    nullptr,
    D3DCOLOR_ARGB(0, 0, 0, 0));
for(int x = 0; x < pLayer->GetWidth(); ++x) {
    for(int y = 0; y < pLayer->GetHeight(); ++y) {
        const Tmx::MapTile tile = pLayer->GetTile(x, y);
        if(tile.tilesetId != -1) {
            int dwTilesetWidth =
            this->m_pTmxFile->GetTileset(tile.tilesetId)->GetImage()->GetWidth() / 16;
            std::div_t tileCoords = std::div(tile.id, dwTilesetWidth);
            RECT srcRect = { tileCoords.rem * 16, tileCoords.quot * 16,
                tileCoords.rem * 16 + 16, tileCoords.quot * 16 + 16 };
            RECT destRect = { x * 16, y * 16, x * 16 + 16, y * 16 + 16 };
            Engine::GetInstance()->GraphicsDevice->StretchRect(
                this->m_vTilesets[tile.tilesetId],
                &srcRect,
                pLayerSurface,
                &destRect,
                D3DTEXF_NONE);
        }
    }
}
```

A call to `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile` for debugging purposes creates transparent png files which can be layered correctly in Photoshop etc. but when I render these surfaces with this loop

```
for(auto iter = this->m_vLayers.begin(); iter != this->m_vLayers.end(); ++iter) {
    Engine::GetInstance()->GraphicsDevice->StretchRect(
        *iter,
        nullptr,
        Engine::GetInstance()->Backbuffer,
        nullptr,
        D3DTEXF_NONE);
}
```

then I have some wrong output which you can see here: [image: Wrong output].

All the blacks areas should be transparent such that one can see the layer below. **Has anyone an idea what I might be doing wrong?**

PS: I have read about the `IDirect3DTexture9` and `ID3DXSprite` interfaces which could be helpful, but I haven't used them yet as I did not find any information on how to rebuild a map with tiles like I did here with usual surfaces. If anyone has suggestions about this, I would be glad to here them!

Comment: Do you actualy have a ground tile? beacuse, trancparancy is otherwise black, or the same color as your clear color of your target

Comment: In my loop where I create all layers, I dump all surfaces to png files to be able to debug. And I get two files, one background and one foreground. You can fetch the output files here: http://imgur.com/a/AnEHI

Comment: well, then it looks correct. lets say your first layer is the background, and the second is the trees and houses. 
The trancparency is still black. since you need to blend them together to get what you want. since 1 + 0 ( 0 equals the trancaprecny ), you will fill that area with your background color.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot follow what you are saying. Could you explain how to blend the two layers together? - EDIT: Are you suggesting that I should not create surfaces for each layer, but iterate throught each layer and fill only one surface?

Comment: To your backbuffer, which are displaying the image. You have to 1 draw the background, then after that, just add on the other image.
what you are doing now is, render the first image, and the render the second image over the first image. you need to add the second ontop of the first. ( im trying to find the correct call for that in dx9 right now. )

Comment: Ah now I understand - I will wait for you to find the function and then try it out.

Comment: The only things i can find seems to be via shaders. And it it was a long time ago since i did something like this with dx9. So the easiest way of achiving this is to render your background, and then iterate through all your objects and render the separate.

Comment: This doesn't sound convenient - I will just wait and see whether someone else has any possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of mh01 and some trial and error I succeeded in drawing my map. I am still loading the tilesets as `IDirect3DSurface9` objects but creating `IDirect3DTexture9` objects for each layer. With a call to `IDirect3DTexture9::GetSurfaceLevel()` I retrieve a pointer to the underlying `IDirect3DSurface9` of the texture which can be used for `StretchRect`. However when I want to draw the layers I must not use `StretchRect` as it does not render but merely copy all contents. Therefore I am relying on a `ID3DXSprite` object which handles this for me successfully.

Answer (score 0):

StretchRect just does a straight copy and so doesn't support any form of alpha blending; you're going to need to find another method of doing this.

Comment: As mentioned in my question I have read about `IDirect3DTexture9`  and `ID3DXSprite` which could come in handy - is this something I should take a look at? And furthermore, do you know which functions I can use to create the layers from my tileset?

Comment: Somebody else is going to have to give this info as working in 2d is not something I have much experience with. If it was me I'd use textures and alpha blending with regular draw calls, which is very different to your approach and would need a total rewrite, but like I said, I don't really know what 2d options are available.